# How to open git terminal on windows

Tags: git

How do i open git terminal[git terminal page]

Was learning how to use git from John Hopkins University coursera material. They guy copied his repository link and said he will paste it in the terminal page which he did but i don't know what he did or what he pressed on his pc to get to this page. Screenshot of this terminal page is attached to this message.

Find video here at 06:30 point; https://www.coursera.org/learn/html-css-javascript-for-web-developers/lecture/4T1t0/development-environment-setup-part-3-github-and-browser-sync

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the previous video "Lecture 5 - Development Environment Setup, Part 2: Windows", which describes how to set up the development environment, especially git from 1:10 onwards. What he opens in your video is the terminal of osx, which you cannot use on your windows pc.

Comment: Thanks bro. Git it now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the program directly or add the git bin folder to your environment variables in control panel> system> advanced settings> environment variable> PATH>  then add git bin directory

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I don't understand u tho. Pls check the link I just put up on the question. I want to know what he did at 06:30. Really appreciate.

Comment: Sorry I was under the understanding you had windows, but I will start up my mac and see if I can find a way to fix this for you

Comment: Thanks. I have Windows. I misunderstood you. Thanks again, I got it now

Answer (score 0):

Download Sourcetree and click the Git Terminal button on the main toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Writing this years later, but I just had the same problem with the same video on coursera using browser sync with CMD on windows.
found the solution on github faqs, dropping it here in case someone needs it :
(I skipped step 4)
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29984374)